# Get specific key out of an array

Tags: php, arrays, key

I have this array:

```
$client = new OAuth2\Client($client_id, $client_secret, $region, $locale, $redirect_uri);

$array = array('id'=>'13146');
$type = 'quest';
$r = $client->fetch($type,$array);
echo '<pre>';
print_r ($r);
echo '</pre>';

?>
```

The output:

```
[result] => Array
    (
        [id] => 13146
        [title] => Generosity Abounds
        [reqLevel] => 77
        [suggestedPartyMembers] => 0
        [category] => Icecrown
        [level] => 80
    )
```

I just want to read out the [title] and the [category]. I´ve tried a a couple of solutions but nothing works for me. Thanks.

Comment: So you want `title` or `Generosity Abounds`?

Comment: Try `echo $r['result']['title']` and `echo $r['result']['category']`

Comment: Try `$r['result']['title']` and `$r['result']['category']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To access `title` and `category` you need to do this:

```
echo $r['result']['title'];    // Generosity Abounds
echo $r['result']['category']; // Icecrown
```

Comment: Thanks works perfectly.